# I don't using canreinvite option in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I want to develop VoIP using asterisk.

Communications between DeviceA and DeviceB are good.

SIP, RTP and most of protocols are go through the Asterisk server.

I hope that go through the server only sip protocol is.

So, I was changing canreinvite option (from no to yes).

But, there is nothing changed.

How to use canreinvite option?

Comment: Ah.. Canreinvite is changed to directmedia. But, it is not work too.

Answer (score 0):

1) it have be set on ALL side of call

2) it have be SAME codec supported on both side

3) very likly after reinvite you never get result or lenght of that call.

Comment: Thanks to advise. I was succeed my work using directrtpsetup option. Asterisk server can't capture RTP. But, my client, too. Communication is doesn't trouble. But, I can't capture rtp anywhere. I saw only sip. Why rtp isn't there?

Comment: Becuase you say directrtpsetup is posible. So your rtp is direct(not via asterisk).

Comment: Um... I want to capturing rtp packet in UC. How can i?

Comment: Sure.

I tries to all of types.

1) directmedia=yes, directrtpsetup=yes
2) directmedia=yes, directrtpsetup=no
3) directmedia=no, directrtpsetup=yes
4) directmedia=no, directrtpsetup=no.

Type 1), 3) are captured only sip.
Type 2), 4) are captured sip,rtp.

Comment: Yes, that is how it expected to be.

Comment: Really? Is it successful result? When captured only sip, is server road lower than captured sip,rtp?

Comment: Without rtp server load and bandwidth much lower. RTP take near 1Mb/minute traffic per channel. If no rtp, traffic is almost zero, but can be issues with cdrs. If  you have codec conversion rtp will go via asterisk,doesn't metter what you have in options.

Answer (score 0):

First, canreinvite (directmedia) should be turned on for both peers engaged in a call.
Second, some application overrides canreinvite. Most famous is MixMonitor.

Comment: Finally, I hope lower server load. So, I used canreinvite(directrtupsetup).Is it be effective?